# Apache and Vagrant issue

Tags: php, laravel, apache, vagrant, homestead

I have a problem with my Laravel/Homestead server installed under a Vagrant VM. I'm kind of new to Vagrant so i'm not sure if i'm explaining the problem well

I decided I wanted to run a website application that required apache. I downloaded the repository. On my Homestead.yaml file under the map, I added the key `type: "apache"` so it's recognized that it has to run on an apache server. This is fine but  the rest of my sites are serving the one site alias I had that runs in apache.  How do I undo this problem, or better yet, how do I get both the one site in the apache site and the rest of the sites to work independently?

Comment: You really ought to have all of the sites served off of the same webserver, otherwise you're going to have to mess with ports. If you've made the change without reprovisioning, I'd suggest you go ahead and do that so all of the sites will convert to apache.

Comment: No what I need is for the one site that needs apache to run under apache, and the rest to run under nginx I believe? There is only one site that should run under an apache server.

Comment: - map: thecontainer.net
     to: /home/vagrant/code/thecontainer
     type: "apache"
- map: therestiofthe.sites
     to: /home/vagrant/code/others
     php: "7.0"

as an example of my sites under Homestead.yaml

Comment: The one site that runs in apache is not supposed to alias for other sites but that's what its doing. All the other site aliases is running what thecontainer.net points to.